# 400 - An error has occurred. Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }'

Tags: php, google-fusion-tables, google-api-php-client

I upgrade my app that had a google fusion tables, and it seemed to work on my laptop, so once i was done, I upgrade my website and I got invalid grant

So I created new service account and a new server app key for my website.  But I keep getting the same error.  I read something about deleting my client secret but that is only for web application I am using a service account.

What else can I do.

This is how i connect.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName("API Project");
        $client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);

        // Set your cached access token. Remember to replace $_SESSION with a
        // real database or memcached.
        if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        }

        $key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);

        $client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
                SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
                array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables'),
                $key)
        );

        //$client->authenticate();

        if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
        }

        if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
            $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        }


        $token = $_SESSION['token'];

        var_dump($token);

        return $token;
```

Answer (score 0):

Damn you dreamhost, the server was 15 minutes into the future.  Learn to use ntp people.  The last thing I checked was the server time on dreamhost.  hoping they can fix this after i opened a support ticket.